# Vertically center parent div on page

Tags: html, css

I know vertical alignment is tricky and there are plenty of questions about it on stackoverflow... I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours, with no success, so decided to ask it (apologies if it is a duplicate)

I have created a login page for my website.

There are 2 main divs in the body, one for logo and one for login content. The login content, has 2 sections, one for email and password and one for social media login.

```
<body>
 <div>
 My Logo goes here
 <div>
 <div>
  <section id="loginForm"></section> 
  <section id="SocialLoginForm"></section> 
 </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to always vertically center the login div? I want the logo to stay on the top, but the login div be vertically centered. **I know I can assign a height to the div and center it's content**, but I don't know how to determine the height as the screen size will change...

this is how it looks like, as you see there is a big gap at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a working snippet for us to work on

Comment: @Swellar, thanks for your comment. It comes with a fairly large css, extracting the gist of it is not easy and I cannot post the whole thing here. I was hoping someone could direct me to the correct method of centering the parent div on the page?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ this may be helpful to you.

Comment: Did you try using `padding`?

Comment: @KhatamNaayak: thanks, no I have not tried padding, how could I do this?

Comment: @sarhang, follow this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try flex like this :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align:center;
}

.logo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.login {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

#loginForm,
#SocialLoginForm {
  min-height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    My Logo goes here
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <section id="loginForm">Login content</section>
    <section id="SocialLoginForm"> social login content</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, if I use this method, then do I need to know the height of my screen and set it on .container?

Comment: @Sarhang you don't have to know the height ;) it will be automatic since i used 100vh

Comment: @Sarhang using 100vh will make it take the whole height of the screen. I added border so you can see it, you make go full screen and test it

Answer (score 2):

You have a few display options:

*`display:table`* (ie8 and above)

```css
  html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
}

body>div {
  display: table-row;
}

body>div+div {

  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  My Logo goes here
</div>
<div>
  <section id="loginForm">lg form</section>
  <section id="SocialLoginForm">socl form</section>
</div>
```

```
display:flex;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div+div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  My Logo goes here
</div>
<div>
  <section id="loginForm">lg form</section>
  <section id="SocialLoginForm">socl form</section>
</div>
```

```
display:grid;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

div+div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  My Logo goes here
</div>
<div>
  <section id="loginForm">lg form</section>
  <section id="SocialLoginForm">socl form</section>
</div>
```

All `display` method require a container with an `height` set.

there can be also method with `transform`, `absolute`, `inline-block` but no need to use tricks nowdays ;)

Comment: Thanks, if I want to use the first method, then do I have to set display: table on body? or can I define a div which wraps everything inside the body and assign display: table to that div?

Comment: @Sarhang , you can use body or use another tag, it remains a tag . display will do the reset to any tag. You can of course use a wrapper if you feel more confident with it or ned to add more contents after it .

Answer (score 1):

```css
body, html{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.my-container{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.my-container .your-div{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid #e3e3e3;
    margin:0 auto;   
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="my-container">

<div class="your-div">

 <div>My Logo goes here<div>
 <div>
  <section id="loginForm">loginForm</section> 
  <section id="SocialLoginForm">SocialLoginForm</section> 
 </div>
 </div>
 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP said : `I want the logo to stay on the top, but the login div be vertically centered.`

Comment: Thanks, if I want to use the first method, then do I have to set display: table on body? or can I define a div which wraps everything inside the body and assign display: table to that div?

Comment: No, you can use my method its according to your markup.

Comment: or why you want to use 1st method ?, I have used your given html

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using preprocessor such as Sass. I would recommend using a mixin like that:

```
@mixin center($axis: "both") {
  position: absolute;
  @if $axis == "y" {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
 @if $axis == "x" {
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
 @if $axis == "both" {
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
  }

body {
  position: relative;
  .inner-div {
    @include center(); //both horizontaly and vertically pass 'x' or 'y' to center veritcally or horizontal
  }
}
```